# How to get the 'reactor' when the twisted application is started by twistd?

Tags: python, service, twisted

My application uses the 'twisted.web.client.Agent' to get web content. But the Agent class requires a 'reactor' instance to initiate. If I start my application using the 'twistd', there will be no 'reactor.run()' at all. So how can I get the 'reactor' instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wish there were a [better answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks), but the way to get the current, active reactor in a Twisted application is:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
```

The important thing is to not do this all over the place, but once near the "top" of your application code, so that you can easily replace the reactor for testing purposes or to modify its behavior in other ways (for example, you could potentially change `connectTCP` to go through a proxy).  That is why `Agent` takes a `reactor` parameter rather than importing the current one itself.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424825/is-twisted-internet-reactor-global). So, the 'reactor' is global. Thanks @Glyph